# Using Modulo on Screen Space Coordinates in GLSL Not Producing Expected Result

Tags: c, glsl, shader

I suppose this is more of a math question than anything.

Here is a basic shader:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    // Time varying pixel color
    vec3 col = 0.5 + 0.5*cos(iTime+uv.xyx+vec3(0,2,4));
    
    if(uv.x < .5) col = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);

    // Output to screen
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}
```

First we are normalizing our X coordinates between (0.0,0.1) with 0.0 being the far left of the screen and 1.0 being the far right. By turning all pixels with x coordinates < .5 black, I am simply masking half the screen in black. This results in the following:

[image]

If I use screen space coordinates I can achieve a similar result, the width of the actual screen is 800 pixels. So I can mask every pixel with an x < 400 with black by doing the following:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    // Time varying pixel color
    vec3 col = 0.5 + 0.5*cos(iTime+uv.xyx+vec3(0,2,4));
    
    if(fragCoord.x < 400.) col = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);

    // Output to screen
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}
```

Which results in the same:
[image]

Logically then, I should be able to use Modulo on the screen space coordinates to create stripes. By taking mod(fragCoord.x,10.0) and checking where the result is 0.0 I should be disabling any row of pixels where its x value is a factor of 10.

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    // Time varying pixel color
    vec3 col = 0.5 + 0.5*cos(iTime+uv.xyx+vec3(0,2,4));
    
    if(mod(fragCoord.x, 10.0) == 0.0) col = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);

    // Output to screen
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}
```

However, what I expect isn't happening:

[image]

Can somebody explain why I am not seeing rows of black pixels wherever x%10 == 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `fragCoord` is set by `gl_FragCoord`.

[`mod`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mod.xhtml) is a floating point operation and the values of [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) are not integral. See Khronos OpenGL reference:

> By default, gl_FragCoord assumes a lower-left origin for window coordinates and assumes pixel centers are located at half-pixel centers. For example, the (x, y) location (0.5, 0.5) is returned for the lower-left-most pixel in a window.

Therefore the result of the modulo operation will never be 0.0. Convert `fragCoord.x` to an integral value and use the `%` operator:

<s>`if(mod(fragCoord.x, 10.0) == 0.0) col = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);`</s>

```c
if (int(fragCoord.x) % 10 == 0) col = vec3(0.0);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This has helped me gain a much better understanding of what's going on!

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody wants to see the result of Rabbid76's answer

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    // Time varying pixel color
    vec3 col = 0.5 + 0.5*cos(iTime+uv.xyx+vec3(0,2,4));
    
    if (int(fragCoord.x) % 10 == 0) col = vec3(0.0);
    // Output to screen
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}
```

[image]